# Htaccess maintenance mode allow certain directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So I use the following for to force my site into maintenance mode while updating certain things:

```
# MAINTENANCE-PAGE REDIRECT
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^23\.1\.12\.167
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
 RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

This has worked well, but now I have the situation when in maintenance mode that I wish to exclude certain dir's from being sent to the maintenance.html and rather have them display their normal contents.

So it would be something like:

```
root/
   .htaccess
    maintenance.html
    index.html
    everything.else.html
    /do_not_display_me
    /display_me_always
```

Not sure if this is possible from the root level .htaccess or if I'm going to have to get crafty with sub-dir .htaccess files, any help is appreciated.

Comment: So .. as I understand you want some folders to ALWAYS be accessible regardless of maintenance mode or not, right? What folders do you want to exclude (I assume you have more than one)?

Comment: @LazyOne - Yes, there are a few dir's that I want to display -- in the above example it would be /display_me_always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the job. It tells Apache to not to rewrite those folders (which makes maintenance rules to be omitted as rewrite chain will never reach them).

```
# activate rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

# always allow these folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/display_me_always [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/another_folder [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/even_more_folders
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# maintenance rules
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^23\.1\.12\.167
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif) [NC]
RewriteRule .* /maintenance.html [R=302,L]
```

1. Letter case matters, so if you need to match mixed case spelling insert `NC,` into `[OR]`.
2. You may consider adding slash `/` at the end of folder names if you have files in root folder with the same names.